# Fail a file download in the middle of process in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an endpoint in Spring MVC controller that allow user to start download a file while I still process necessary data on the server. The endpoint looks like this:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/download.csv")
public void download(HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name.csv");
        final List listOfIds = getListOfIds();
        for (id in ids) {
            final String data = getAdditionalData(id)
            write(data, response.getOutputStream())
            response.flushBuffer()
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       // handle error
    }
}
```

This code works fine, when the user accesses the download endpoint, the web browser will immediately ask if the user wants to save the file. Then I can process the expensive `getAdditionalData(id)` calls on the server during user downloading, instead of letting the user wait until I processed all the `ids` which could take a long time.

However, there is one problem: when `getAdditionalData(id)` fails and throws an exception, the web browser will show the download as "completed" instead of "failed" and leave a partial result to the user.

My problem is: is there any way from this endpoint to tell the web browser the download has failed so it won't show "completed" to the user? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the `HttpServletResponse` yourself. You should never bypass Spring. Use a `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>` instead.

Comment: Try preventing it by getting all the `data` ready and handling exception before you put it into the response stream.